# how can i create a telegram bot for save urls?

Tags: telegram-bot

it's my first bot and i'm trying to create one that save the urls send from the user
it should put the urls with **/put <link/to/send/>** and to fetch the url a command like **/get**
someone can help me for write the code? i saw a few scripts but they are not for the same purpose and i don't know from where i can start
I prefer java or python
i already tried to write a simple code for response writed inside the code, like **time?** and it answered with the current time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Python with dedicated libraries, here you go. https://kandi.openweaver.com/collections/python/python-telegram-bot